# Linear map construction

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure how to approach this problem:

Constuct a linear map $L:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^3}$ such that $L(1,0)=(1,-1,-1)$ and $L(1,1)=(2,3,0).$

How about if I were asked to construct a non-linear map?

Answer (score 0):

Since $L(0,1) = L(1,1)-L(1,0) = (1,4,1)$ a linear is$$L = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ -1&4\\ -1&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Nonlinear: $$L(x,y) = (x^2+y^2,4y-x,y^2-x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

To make a linear map note that, as vectors,  $(0,1)=(1,1)-(1,0)$  So $$L(0,1)=L(1,1)-L(1,0)=(2,3,0)-(1,-1,-1)=(1,4,1)$$

Then $$L(x,y)=x\times (1,-1,-1)+y\times (1,4,1)$$

Nonlinear examples  are easy:

Just set $L(\vec v)=\vec 0$ for all $\vec v$ other than the two given points.